# R: Assigning variable to quintile on monthly basis

Tags: r, variable-assignment, stocks, quantile, volatility

I am trying in R to indicate in which quintile a value of a variable is for every month of my data frame in this case based on volatility.
For each month I want to know for each stock if it is in the most volatile quintile of if it is in one of the others.

So far I have come up with the following function (see below). Unfortunately, the function only works in some cases and often gives the following error:

```
Error in cut.default(df$VOLATILITY, unique(breaks), label = FALSE, na.rm =TRUE): 
  invalid number of intervals
```

Could you give me some advice on how to improve this code so that it works properly.

It's relatively urgent. Many thanks!

```
quintilesVolByMonth <- function(x){
  months<-as.vector(unique(x$DATE))  
  dfx<-data.frame()
  for(n in seq(1,length(months))){
    num<-5
    print(paste("Appending month",months[n],sep=""))
    df<-subset(x,DATE==months[n])
    breaks<-quantile(df$VOLATILITY,probs=seq(0,1, 1/num),na.rm=TRUE)
    df$volquintile <- cut(df$VOLATILITY,unique(breaks), 
                       label=FALSE, na.rm=TRUE)
    dfx<-rbind(dfx,df)
  }
  return(dfx)
}
Frame.Quintile <- quintilesVolByMonth(x)
```

EXAMPLE OF THE DATA: The last column is what I am trying to get. The data here is just an example and not actual results.

```
> DATE <- c("01/10/2011","01/10/2012","01/10/2010","01/08/2010","01/10/2011","01/12/2011","01/09/2011","01/10/2011","01/09/2012","01/08/2012","01/02/2010","01/01/2011","01/09/2010","01/06/2010","01/07/2010","01/01/2012","01/01/2012","01/11/2011","01/09/2011","01/10/2011")
> NAME<-c("HOEK'S MACHINE DEAD - DELIST.","WORLD SCOPE (CADB TEST STOCK)","BRILL (KON.)",   "BBL DEAD - 30/06/465", "GENK LOGISTICS","GROENIJK.YLCBN. DEAD - DELIST.31/05/479", "NOORD-EUR.HOUTH.","PALTHE DEAD - 4/2/475","GENERALE BANQUE DEAD - DEL. 30/12/490","STORK DEAD - TAKEOVER 905099","LOUVAIN-LA-NEUVE","VENTOS DEAD - 06/06/384","BRAINE-LE-COMTE SUSP 14/02/460","VILENZO DEAD - 25/11/370","ECONOSTO KON. DEAD - 07/07/374","ELECTRORAIL DEAD - DELIST 21/02/387","BLYSTEIN FL.1384","OBOURG (CIMENTS)","BRUGEFI DEAD - 31/07/475","GIB NEW")
> VOLATILITY<-c(0.3383, 0.084,  0.046,  0.0945, 0.0465, 0.2008, 0.1361, 0.2183, 0.1032, 0.1083, 0.0494, 0.0538, 0.0357, 0.037,  0.0386, 0.073,  0.073,  0.0393, 0.0687, 0.3308)
> VOLQUINTILE<-c(4,1,1,2,2,3,2,3,4,2,3,2,4,1,2,1,1,2,3,4)
>   
> x<-data.frame(DATE,NAME,VOLATILITY, VOLQUINTILE)
> x
         DATE                                    NAME VOLATILITY VOLQUINTILE
1  01/10/2011           HOEK'S MACHINE DEAD - DELIST.     0.3383           4
2  01/10/2012           WORLD SCOPE (CADB TEST STOCK)     0.0840           1
3  01/10/2010                            BRILL (KON.)     0.0460           1
4  01/08/2010                    BBL DEAD - 30/06/465     0.0945           2
5  01/10/2011                          GENK LOGISTICS     0.0465           2
6  01/12/2011 GROENIJK.YLCBN. DEAD - DELIST.31/05/479     0.2008           3
7  01/09/2011                        NOORD-EUR.HOUTH.     0.1361           2
8  01/10/2011                   PALTHE DEAD - 4/2/475     0.2183           3
9  01/09/2012   GENERALE BANQUE DEAD - DEL. 30/12/490     0.1032           4
10 01/08/2012            STORK DEAD - TAKEOVER 905099     0.1083           2
11 01/02/2010                        LOUVAIN-LA-NEUVE     0.0494           3
12 01/01/2011                 VENTOS DEAD - 06/06/384     0.0538           2
13 01/09/2010          BRAINE-LE-COMTE SUSP 14/02/460     0.0357           4
14 01/06/2010                VILENZO DEAD - 25/11/370     0.0370           1
15 01/07/2010          ECONOSTO KON. DEAD - 07/07/374     0.0386           2
16 01/01/2012     ELECTRORAIL DEAD - DELIST 21/02/387     0.0730           1
17 01/01/2012                        BLYSTEIN FL.1384     0.0730           1
18 01/11/2011                        OBOURG (CIMENTS)     0.0393           2
19 01/09/2011                BRUGEFI DEAD - 31/07/475     0.0687           3
20 01/10/2011                                 GIB NEW     0.3308           4
```

Comment: reproducible example please?

Comment: I agree with Ben. As a small side note, be aware that if you ever apply this code to medium/large amounts of data, it will be extremely slow. Creating an empty data frame and then `rbind`ing pieces onto it will in general be very inefficient.

Comment: I've added an example. What method do you think would be more efficient joran?

Comment: `months<-as.vector(unique(x$DATE))` seems more likely to give you unique days than it would be to give you unique months. You are probably getting too few items to properly form quintiles.

Comment: Is there a way to omit the months during which there are too few items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
library(plyr)
vol1<-ddply(mydata,.(DATE), transform, max.name=NAME[which.max(quantile(VOLATILITY))])
             DATE                                    NAME VOLATILITY                                max.name
    1  01/01/2011                 VENTOS DEAD - 06/06/384     0.0538                 VENTOS DEAD - 06/06/384
    2  01/01/2012     ELECTRORAIL DEAD - DELIST 21/02/387     0.0730     ELECTRORAIL DEAD - DELIST 21/02/387
    3  01/01/2012                        BLYSTEIN FL.1384     0.0730     ELECTRORAIL DEAD - DELIST 21/02/387
    4  01/02/2010                        LOUVAIN-LA-NEUVE     0.0494                        LOUVAIN-LA-NEUVE
    5  01/06/2010                VILENZO DEAD - 25/11/370     0.0370                VILENZO DEAD - 25/11/370
    6  01/07/2010          ECONOSTO KON. DEAD - 07/07/374     0.0386          ECONOSTO KON. DEAD - 07/07/374
    7  01/08/2010                    BBL DEAD - 30/06/465     0.0945                    BBL DEAD - 30/06/465
    8  01/08/2012            STORK DEAD - TAKEOVER 905099     0.1083            STORK DEAD - TAKEOVER 905099
    9  01/09/2010          BRAINE-LE-COMTE SUSP 14/02/460     0.0357          BRAINE-LE-COMTE SUSP 14/02/460
    10 01/09/2011                        NOORD-EUR.HOUTH.     0.1361                                    <NA>
    11 01/09/2011                BRUGEFI DEAD - 31/07/475     0.0687                                    <NA>
    12 01/09/2012   GENERALE BANQUE DEAD - DEL. 30/12/490     0.1032   GENERALE BANQUE DEAD - DEL. 30/12/490
    13 01/10/2010                            BRILL (KON.)     0.0460                            BRILL (KON.)
    14 01/10/2011           HOEK'S MACHINE DEAD - DELIST.     0.3383                                    <NA>
    15 01/10/2011                          GENK LOGISTICS     0.0465                                    <NA>
    16 01/10/2011                   PALTHE DEAD - 4/2/475     0.2183                                    <NA>
    17 01/10/2011                                 GIB NEW     0.3308                                    <NA>
    18 01/10/2012           WORLD SCOPE (CADB TEST STOCK)     0.0840           WORLD SCOPE (CADB TEST STOCK)
    19 01/11/2011                        OBOURG (CIMENTS)     0.0393                        OBOURG (CIMENTS)
    20 01/12/2011 GROENIJK.YLCBN. DEAD - DELIST.31/05/479     0.2008 GROENIJK.YLCBN. DEAD - DELIST.31/05/479
```

Updated solution:

```
library(plyr)    


   vol2<-ddply(x,.(DATE), transform,quantile=ifelse(VOLATILITY<quantile(VOLATILITY,p=0.25),1,
ifelse(((VOLATILITY>quantile(VOLATILITY,p=0.25))& (VOLATILITY<quantile(VOLATILITY,p=0.5))),2,ifelse(((VOLATILITY>quantile(VOLATILITY,p=0.5))& VOLATILITY<quantile(VOLATILITY,p=0.75)),3,4))))

       DATE                                    NAME VOLATILITY   quantile
1  01/01/2011                 VENTOS DEAD - 06/06/384     0.0538        4
2  01/01/2012     ELECTRORAIL DEAD - DELIST 21/02/387     0.0730        4
3  01/01/2012                        BLYSTEIN FL.1384     0.0730        4
4  01/02/2010                        LOUVAIN-LA-NEUVE     0.0494        4
5  01/06/2010                VILENZO DEAD - 25/11/370     0.0370        4
6  01/07/2010          ECONOSTO KON. DEAD - 07/07/374     0.0386        4
7  01/08/2010                    BBL DEAD - 30/06/465     0.0945        4
8  01/08/2012            STORK DEAD - TAKEOVER 905099     0.1083        4
9  01/09/2010          BRAINE-LE-COMTE SUSP 14/02/460     0.0357        4
10 01/09/2011                        NOORD-EUR.HOUTH.     0.1361        4
11 01/09/2011                BRUGEFI DEAD - 31/07/475     0.0687        1
12 01/09/2012   GENERALE BANQUE DEAD - DEL. 30/12/490     0.1032        4
13 01/10/2010                            BRILL (KON.)     0.0460        4
14 01/10/2011           HOEK'S MACHINE DEAD - DELIST.     0.3383        4
15 01/10/2011                          GENK LOGISTICS     0.0465        1
16 01/10/2011                   PALTHE DEAD - 4/2/475     0.2183        2
17 01/10/2011                                 GIB NEW     0.3308        3
18 01/10/2012           WORLD SCOPE (CADB TEST STOCK)     0.0840        4
19 01/11/2011                        OBOURG (CIMENTS)     0.0393        4
20 01/12/2011 GROENIJK.YLCBN. DEAD - DELIST.31/05/479     0.2008        4
```

Comment: Yes partially, only I would like to know that stock X is in quantile 2 and stock Y is in quantile 4 and so on...

Comment: The last column is the output I am trying to get.

Comment: If you are looking across each month, then I don't think your expected output is what you actually are expecting. See my updated answers.

Comment: This is the output I was looking for. The only problem that remains is that when volatility is zero for some values the solution doesn't work properly. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Please check [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html) :  

`As long as VOLATILITY is numeric vector there shouldn't be any problem. Note that NA and NaN values are not allowed in numeric vectors unless na.rm is TRUE`.

Comment: VOLATILITY is indeed a numeric vetor. There is no error showed but the problem is that the function assigns a lot of values in the earliest years to quartile 1 and almost no values to quartile 4 in the last years of my data set. So every quartile contains less and less values and of less and less later years... Not sure if it's clear what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Note that the `quantile` is formed for each unique date. So the quartile in one date has nothing to do with the quartile in other dates.But, it does depend upon how many observations you have in each date. 
If this doesn't answer what you are looking for, please try posting the new question regarding this with reproducible example (with output).